# Regex match and increment filename (n)

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to write a regex for usage in ensuring no file name collision.

So I give the user the ability to *save as* some name, and then I check the string against an array, and if there is a collision I follow the Windows saving paradigm.

If you save `test` it'll save as `test`, if you try and save `test` again it'll become `test (1)`. Now I want to look for that `(1)` so

**Conditions**

it will always start with `(` and then N amount of 0-9 characters and ends with `)`.

**How could I look for `(1)` or `(169)` with regex?**
I'm not sure exactly the shortest amount of characters I can write this Regex as. Also as a secondary regex how would I have the same but also look for the same regex but with a space before the `(`?

**Attempt:**

What I came up with `const regEx = RegExp(/(?:\()[0-9*](?:\))/)` however this only works for `(1)` but not `(11)` and I don't know how to also look for a space before the `(`

This is likely very easy but I'm not very experienced with regex.

**String samples that should/n't work**

```
// Should work:
test (1)
test (594)
test (54)

// Shouldn't work
test (1
test 594)
test 54
```

Comment: `[0-9]+`, not `[0-9*]`...

Comment: It is usually helpful if you include some examples of strings that should match and strings that should not match.

Comment: @benvc true, i should've had it more explicit and sectioned off and more examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string should **end** with `space(one or more digits)endOfString` so you could:

```
\s\((\d+)\)$
```

the additional brackets (*Capturing Group*) around `\d+` are for you to extract the number:

https://regex101.com/r/5OFix0/1

### Matching

```js
const sample = `test (0)
test (12)
test()
test(1)
test 1
ends with space (123) `;


sample.split('\n').forEach(fileName => {

  const m = /\s\((\d+)\)$/.exec(fileName);
 
  if (m && m[1]) {       // if is incremented, AKA "fileName (n)"
    console.log(m[1]); // do your stuff here using m[1] string
  }

});
```

### Matching and Replacing

Here's an example given a sample of filenames (without extensions):

```js
/**
 * Detect " (n)" suffixed string. Return "n"
 * @param {String} name
 * @return {String|null} The integer string or null
 */
const isFilenameIncremented = name => {
  const m = /\s\((\d+)\)$/.exec(name);
  return m && m[1];
};

/**
 * Increment unsuffixed or " (n)" suffixed string
 * @dependency {Function} isFilenameIncremented
 * @param {String} name
 * @return {String} The " ((n|0)+1)" suffixed filename
 */
const incrementFilename = name => {
  const isInc = isFilenameIncremented(name);
  return isInc ? name.replace(/\d+(?=\)$)/, m => (+m)+1) : `${name} (1)`;
}


const sample = `test (0)
test (12)
test()
test(1)
test 1
ends with space (123) `;

sample.split('\n').forEach(filename => {
  const fileNameIncr = incrementFilename(filename);
  console.log( fileNameIncr )
});
```

Which should increment only the two first filenames (0 to 1 and 12 to 13) and append `(1)` to all the other ones resulting in the following:

```
test (1)  
test (13)  
test() (1)  
test(1) (1)  
test 1 (1)  
ends with space (123)  (1)
```

Clearly, what's still missing above is a check for if that filename already exists in an array of *filenames* which can be easily achieved by using `fileNamesArray.includes(fileName)`